# Not understanding the behavior of _id on ES

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have documents in a Mongo database, they use the _id field as an index.

I use Monstache to sync ES with Mongo's op log, so the documents in ES have the same _id field.

When searching a specific document, Kibana shows:

> Tags:
>       tag1 testtag CreatedOn:
>       October 26th 2018, 14:25:57.053
>   _id:
>       FRaqDPIzWcVI2dl-oA9uUFHLVFQk8qIqqhySWSkM7Ds
>   _type:
>       testobject
>   _index:
>       test.object
>   _score:
>       0

but then a query with Nest, returns this in the Documents array:

> _id = 0d5aa177-3066-4c6a-aaf5-9b887ae7297f

and when I look in the Hits array, I see:

> Id = FRaqDPIzWcVI2dl-oA9uUFHLVFQk8qIqqhySWSkM7Ds

So in Documents, the _id is now an unrelated guid, but in Hits the _id is called Id and it has the right value.

Why is that, and is there a way to get the proper value for _id in Documents?

---

Edit: more info

This is the object; since it's shared by MongoDB and ES, it has attributes for both.

```
[Nest.ElasticsearchType, BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class TestObject
{
                                                public string       _id                 { get; set; }
                                                public string       OwnerId             { get; set; }
                                                public Flags        Flags               { get; set; }
    [Nest.Text, BsonIgnoreIfDefault]            public string       Title               { get; set; }
    [Nest.Text]                                 public string       Tags                { get; set; }
    [Nest.Ignore]                               public string       Hash                { get; set; }
    [Nest.Ignore, BsonIgnoreIfDefault]          public string       Link                { get; set; }

}
```

This is the code creating the index:

```
   private static void InitializeElasticSearch(string ConnectionString)
    {
        var Settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(ConnectionString))
            .DefaultIndex(_IndexName)
            .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(_ => _)
            .DefaultMappingFor<TestObject>(_ => _.Ignore(I => I._id));


        _ElasticClient = new ElasticClient(Settings);

        if (!_ElasticClient.IndexExists(_IndexName).Exists)
        {
            // create the index
            var CreateIndexResponse = _ElasticClient.CreateIndex(_IndexName, C => C
                .Settings(S => S
                    .Analysis(A => A
                        .CharFilters(Cf => Cf
                            .Mapping("expressions", E => E
                                .Mappings(TextLists.Expressions)
                            )
                        )
                        .TokenFilters(Tf => Tf
                            .Synonym("synonyms", Sy => Sy
                                .Synonyms(TextLists.Synonyms)
                                .Tokenizer("whitespace")
                            )
                        )
                        .Analyzers(An => An
                            .Custom("index", Ca => Ca
                                .CharFilters("expressions")
                                .Tokenizer("standard")
                                .Filters("standard", "synonyms", "stop")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Mappings(M => M
                    .Map<TestObject>(Mm => Mm
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Properties(P => P
                            .Text(T => T
                                .Name(N => N.Title)
                                .Analyzer("index")
                            )
                            .Text(T => T
                                .Name(N => N.Tags)
                                .Analyzer("index")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

Then, the query code:

```
        var R = await _ElasticClient.SearchAsync<TestObject>(Sr => Sr
            .Query(Q =>
            {
                // do we query 'all' ?
                if (Terms == "*") return Q.MatchAll();

                // or do we have a general query
                return Q
                    .MultiMatch(Fu => Fu
                        .Fields(F => F
                            .Field(Ff => Ff.Tags)
                            .Field(Ff => Ff.Title)
                        )
                        .Query(Terms)
                        .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))
                    );
            })
            .Take(_MaxObjectReturned)
        );
```

Comment: Please can you show the code for: (a) your POCO that maps to the documents in the index, (b) the mapping in the index and (c) the client call used to fetch the documents.

Comment: @RussCam, I have added the object, index and search calls.